# To predict a "0" or a "1" from a series of numbers

Tags: probability

I have a column of numbers they are either a 1 or a 0. The numbers simply represents when an event has occurred or not occurred. 1= event occurred 0 = a non event. The average occurrence of the event is between 5 and 6.

My question is how can I with any degree of accuracy predict when the next event will occur.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple columns and in each column there's at most one event? Or do you have one column and on average each 5th/6th entry is an event?

Comment: I have 1 column of data and on average an event occurs 5th/6th times.

Comment: The event may and most often does not occur every 5/6 time but this is the average.

Answer (score 0):

The relative frequency can be used as an approximation for the probability. Let's assume the probablity to be around $p=0.18$. We now roughly expect 1 Event per 5.5 Events. Unfortunately that is not really good for predictions, because this assumes it's totally random and that events are totally independent, which is not a good starting point for predictions.

However, you can use the binomial distribution to estimate the probability for at least $k$ events in $n$ draws.

$$P(X>=k)= 1-\sum \limits_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix}n\\\ell\end{pmatrix} p^\ell (1-p)^{n-\ell}$$

```
  n | P(x>=1)
  1 | 0.18
  2 | 0.3276
  3 | 0.4486
  4 | 0.5479
  5 | 0.6293
  6 | 0.6960
  7 | 0.7507
  8 | 0.7956
  9 | 0.8324
 10 | 0.8626
 11 | 0.8873
 12 | 0.9076
 13 | 0.9242
 14 | 0.9379
 15 | 0.9404
 16 | 0.9582
 17 | 0.9657
 18 | 0.9719
 19 | 0.9770
 20 | 0.9811
```

So as expected, the probability to get at least one event increases with the number of rows. You can already be 90% sure to have at least 1 event within 12 rows.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my question, Can you explain the formula please. If P=.18 then why are the values between 1 & 20 at variable amounts. What would happen if during the 20 events that a strike would occur, Would you simply start calculating again. How would one account for 2 or three strikes together or within say 5 events?